# How to use the Switch widget in android

Tags: android, widget

I working on Android Views and using Switch View in my design. I'm getting errors like:

> Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
>   Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.
>
> Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

I am unable to fix this error can anyone please help.

Also share your implementation on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing the theme of my activity, use the DeviceDefault Theme and it will work.

Comment: What about if I dont want to change my custom theme?